# To transmit an information without waiting of receiving it

Tags: expressions

On network technology a system can start sending data without having received the totality of the message. What is the word to say it in English? In French there is an expression **transmettre à la volée** but I don't think it should be literally translated...

Comment: Although *traduce* is an English word, it's fairly rare and the "translate" meaning is now archaic.  You probably want to say "literally translated" instead.

Comment: Slightly on-topic: information is normally not countable. So you transmit _information_, and not _an information_. You could transmit _a piece of information_, though.

Comment: Beside "transmit data on the fly" or "streaming data", I think you can also say "relay data in real-time". The verb *relay* conveys the sense of transmitting data without changing it.

Comment: When we discuss this concept (I'm a developer) we say either or. For longer streams it's *to relay* as in *to lay (the information) again or *to (bounce) forward*. For shorter messages it's *fire-and-forget* or *to dispatch (async)*. What you describe sounds to me most similar to the first option. So, *to **relay***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To transmit (a stream of) data *on the fly*" or "to stream (data) (on the fly)"

I guess it is a fairly direct translation, *transmettre à la volée* = *transmit on the fly*.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are *streaming* data?

A data stream means that you process your data (resend it, store it, send it to a media player, whatever) without waiting for all the data be retrieved.